# EF Core - hierarchy using Composite Design Pattern and CTE

Tags: entity-framework-core, composite

I want to create a catalog products. There may be catalogs or products on each node.

I decided to use the composite design pattern.

I will download the node with the children using CTE. Unfortunately there was a problem, because EF Core doesn't add parentId in the CategoryProducts table. 
Additionally the class (Category as my Composite) has its own CategoryDetails class, (Product as my Leaf) has its own ProductDetails class.

How do I configure EF Core to recursively get nodes from the tree?
Is CTE a good idea?

```
public enum CategoryProductType
{
    Category,
    Product
}

public abstract class CategoryProduct
{
    public Guid Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public CategoryProductType Type { get; private set; }

    protected CategoryProduct(Guid id, string name, CategoryProductType type)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Type = type;
    }
```

}

```
public class Category : CategoryProduct
{
    public string Code { get; private set; }
    public CategoryDetails CategoryDetails { get; private set; }

    private ICollection<CategoryProduct> _children { get; set; } = new Collection<CategoryProduct>();
    public IEnumerable<CategoryProduct> Children => _children;

    public Category(Guid id, string name, string code) 
        : base(id, name, CategoryProductType.Category) 
    {
        Code = code;
    }
```

}

```
public class CategoryDetails
{
    public Guid CategoryId { get; private set; }
    public Category Category { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }

    private CategoryDetails() { }

    public CategoryDetails(Category category, string description)
    {
        Category = category);
        Description = description);
    }
```

}

```
public class Product : CategoryProduct
{
    public string Index { get; private set; }
    public ProductDetails ProductDetails { get; private set; }

    public Product(Guid id, string name, string index) 
        : base(id, name, CategoryProductType.Product) 
    {
        SetIndex(index);
    }
```

}

EF Core Setting: [image]

Comment: Please explain what CTE means

Comment: Once the tables are properly designed, I want to insert the sample data and write CTE Recursion  to get tree hierarchy

https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-recursive-cte/

Comment: why you don't create two separate tables, one for categories and one for products?

Comment: Yes, products and categories are totally different entities. Putting them into one class hierarchy and one table causes more trouble than joy.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I create Category class like Paolo showed me? Then the Product class will be linked with CatalogId (as public key)  with the Catalog class? Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @ka_lib_dev Do you find any solution for modeling composit pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know anything about CTE Recursion.

However, this is an example on how I modeled a hierarchical structure (i.e. a tree) with EF Core, hopefully it can help you.

```cs
public class TreeNode
{
    public int TreeNodeId { get; private set; }
    public int? ParentTreeNodeId { get; set; }
    public TreeNode ParentTreeNode { get; set; }
    public List<TreeNode> ChildrenTreeNodes { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<TreeNode>(entity =>
    {
        entity.HasOne(n => n.ParentTreeNode)
            .WithMany(n => n.ChildrenTreeNodes)
            .HasForeignKey(n => n.ParentTreeNodeId);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I need two types:  Catalog that can have children and a Product that can't have them.

I don't know if my solution is good. I'll have to download the tree hierarchy later. In EF Core I can't get data recursivelly, so I'm thinking about cte.